# React event.preventDefault() is not working when uploading attachment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have an attachment upload feature using React-Bootstrap form and unfortunately, every time I upload an attachment, the page keeps refreshing and signs me out of the application. I have inserted `e.preventDefault()` in all functions; `saveFile` which saves the name of the file from input, `backToProject` which returns to the previous page, and `uploadFile` to upload the file to MySQL using NodeJS. However, it does not work.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Axios from "axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext, UserTypeContext } from "./../Helper/Context";

function AddAttachment() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const { userId, setUserId } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { type, isUserType } = useContext(UserTypeContext);

  const link = window.location.pathname;
  const split = link.split("/");
  const projectId = split[4];

  const [proCode, setProCode] = useState("");

  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");

  const saveFile = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const uploadFile = async (e, projectId) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("fileName", fileName);
    formData.append("projectId", projectId);
    try {
      const res = await Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3001/uplatt",
        formData
      ).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.successfulAdd) {
          if (type === "Staff") {
            window.alert("You have successfully uploaded an attachment!");
            history.push(`/staff/${userId}/viewproject/${projectId}`);
          } else if (type === "Student") {
            window.alert("You have successfully uploaded an attachment!");
            history.push(`/student/${userId}/viewproject/${projectId}`);
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  };

  const backToProject = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (type === "Staff") {
      history.push(`/staff/${userId}/viewproject/${projectId}`);
    } else if (type === "Student") {
      history.push(`/student/${userId}/viewproject/${projectId}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <Card style={{ width: "70%" }}>
        <div className="mt-3 p-5">
          <h3>Add new attachment</h3>
          <hr />
          <Form onSubmit={(e) => uploadFile(e, projectId)}>
            <div className="mt-1 mb-3">
              <input type="file" name="file" onChange={saveFile} />
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex flex-end justify-content-end align-items-end mt-3">
              <div className="px-3">
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#104271" }}
                  onClick={backToProject}
                  className="mr-3"
                >
                  Cancel
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#104271" }}
                >
                  Upload
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddAttachment;
```

I am just wondering what is wrong with my code? Can anybody please, please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a full live example, with code snippet of stackoverflow or any live editor like code sandbox

Comment: Why are you using await with .then?

Comment: @MilosPavlovic because I am sending them to backend and then getting the response from backend in then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but absolutely have no idea why. I changed from client side to server side (uploaded the files to public/images of server instead of client) and boom, the problem's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Your page refresh before the upload end.

You can remove type="submit" from the button and call uploadFile function in in button directly.

```
<Button style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#104271" }}
onClick={async () => {
// do somthing else before
await uploadFile(projectId);
// do somthing else after
}}> Upload </Button>
```

Comment: It does not work